# How to change JMeter execution target browser?

Tags: browser, jmeter, http-headers, cross-browser

My Web page is not compatible other than Chrome, Firefox and safari browser. Developers has applied some restrictions for not to login this web page other than above mentioned browser for e.g. (IE or Edge). Manually if i tried to use this web page in IE then a message is getting appear on page which showing that this web is not compatible with this browser.

When I am recording this page using JMeter and executing it. Same message i can see in View Result Tree. It means that JMeter executing the script in non-compatible browser may be (IE).

Is there any option or command where I can change the execution target browser to Chrome or Firefox for executing Jmeter scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Web applications mostly distinguish browsers by [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header so it should be sufficient to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send the required [User Agent String](https://deviceatlas.com/blog/list-of-user-agent-strings)

[image]

You might also be interested in How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser article which provides more recommendations on properly configuring JMeter for [building web test plans](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html).